Recursive type for Zod schema to allow multiple "ZodEffects" or just a simple ZodObject type
I try to build a type in TypeScript to allow a function to receive an argument of the following type, using Zod package:
ZodEffects<ZodEffects<ZodEffects<....>>>>

But, I also want to allow simple ZodObject<ZodRawShape>>.
And, the recursive ZodEffects should wrap eventually ZodObject<ZodRawShape>>.
So - it should look like:
type Schema = ZodEffects<Schema> | ZodObject<ZodRawShape>

const yazif = (schema: Schema) => {
}

I'd like to accept only those kind of types in the yazif function:
ZodObject<ZodRawShape>
ZodEffects<ZodObject<ZodRawShape>>
ZodEffects<ZodEffects<ZodObject<ZodRawShape>>>
ZodEffects<ZodEffects<ZodEffects<ZodObject<ZodRawShape>>>

Those should be forbidden:
ZodEffects<ZodEffects<ZodEffects<ZodString>>

So as you can understand I only want to accept ZodObjects for the function, or types that are wrapped by ZodEffects (possibly multiple times).
My schema would look like:
import { z } from "zod";

export const searchPostsSchema = z.object({
    riki: z.string()
});

or also:
import { z } from "zod";

export const searchPostsSchema = z.object({
    riki: z.string()
}).refine().refine().refine();

and my yazif function should accept such schemas.
Thank you
I expect my function to receive recursive types.
